# spring session redis 'No bean named 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' is defined'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-session

JDK1.7
Tomcat8
Redis sv 3.0
Spring3.2.14, jedis 2.8.1, spring session 1.2, spring data redis 1.7

```
[INFO ][XmlBeanDefinitionReader(loadBeanDefinitions:316)] Loading XML bean definitions 
[INFO ][DefaultListableBeanFactory(preInstantiateSingletons:603)] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@66039e85: defining beans [redisHttpSessionConfiguration,jedisPoolConfig,jedisConnectionFactory,redisTemplate]; root of factory hierarchyerere
[INFO ][ContextLoader(initWebApplicationContext:325)] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 361 ms
[ERROR][StandardContext(filterStart:4592)] Exception starting filter springSessionRepositoryFilter
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
```

here's my log.
I don't know how to solve this problem.
it looks like the RedisHttpSessionConfiguration bean had already been created,
why the filter bean still not defined ?

and i cant change to spring4 because my company won't let me
really need your help, thanks

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<!-- redis -->
<bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
</bean>

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory"     class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
<property name="hostName" value="127.0.0.1"/>
<property name="port" value="6739" />
<property name="password" value="" />
<property name="timeout" value="1800" />
<property name="poolConfig" ref="jedisPoolConfig" />
<property name="usePool" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- session redis -->
<bean id="redisHttpSessionConfiguration" class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration">
<property name="maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds" value="1800" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

this is my config file, and my project used embedded tomcat, and didn't have 
web.xml , I add the listener and filters by

```
 ctx.addParameter("contextConfigLocation", "file:"+getHomePath()+"conf/applicationContext.xml");
      ctx.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener("org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener",true));
      ctx.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener("org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener",true));



    org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDefspringSessionRepositoryFilterDef =new org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterDef();
    org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterMap springSessionRepositoryFilterMapper = new org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.FilterMap();

    springSessionRepositoryFilterDef.setFilterName("springSessionRepositoryFilter");
    springSessionRepositoryFilterDef.setFilterClass(org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.class.getCanonicalName());
    ctx.addFilterDef(springSessionRepositoryFilterDef);
    springSessionRepositoryFilterMapper.setFilterName("springSessionRepositoryFilter");
    springSessionRepositoryFilterMapper.addURLPattern("/*");
    ctx.addFilterMap(springSessionRepositoryFilterMapper);
```

thank you very much

Comment: Can you post your config? Also, try debugging `SpringHttpSessionConfiguration.springSessionRepositoryFilter` to verify that the bean is being created.

Comment: @codependent I edited my question, thanks

Comment: @wade You can add it where's the rest of your Spring Session related config. See [XML configuration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/xml-redis.html#httpsession-xml-spring-configuration) from the reference manual as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` to your Spring XML config in order to enable handling of `@Configuration` classes.

As shown in your log output, `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` is currently only registered as a regular bean, but bean definitions inside it are not handled.

Comment: Add `<context:annotation-config/>` where in the Spring XML config?